# How can I wait for page load in selenium before moving to another page? (C#)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am kinda new to selenium, basically, what I am trying to do is login to website1, wait until the page is fully loaded. And move to website2. 
I don't want to use `Thread.Sleep()`  as you know this will make my UI unresponsive.
How can I make that using selenium with c#.

```
        MyWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url1);
        MyWebDriver.FindElement(By.Name(Username_Input)).SendKeys(username);
        MyWebDriver.FindElement(By.Name(Password_Input)).SendKeys(password);
        MyWebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(Log_in_Button)).Click();
        //wait untill the page is fully loaded then move to url2
        MyWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url2);
```

I found an answer which is using ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible but unfortunately I can't find ExpectedConditions in the new selenium version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete")); 

if(wait == true)
{
    //Your code
}
```

Above code will wait for page to load for 60 seconds and return true if page is ready(within 60 seconds), false if page is not ready (after 60 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

As DebanjanB said we no need to wait for complete page load. Rather you can  try below method:

```
MyWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url2);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(dr.FindElement(By.Name("User_Name"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally as a part of a *validation process* you don't wait for a page to load, rather you wait to *verify* the end result of an *action* either in terms of :

- An `ElementIsVisible`
- An `ElementToBeClickable`
- Some `TextToBePresentInElement`
- The `TitleContains`
- The `UrlContains`
- etc

  So your *Automation Script* will be validating any of the above mentioned *validation points*.

  As per the [*API Docs (C#)*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/) the [*ExpectedConditions Class*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) does mentions about the method [*ElementIsVisible*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) as follows :

### `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` Method

An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

- Namespace: `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`
- Assembly: `WebDriver.Support (in WebDriver.Support.dll) Version: 3.1.0`
- Parameters (locator) :

  - Type : `OpenQA.Selenium.By`
  - Return Value : Type: `Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement>`

Screenshot :

[image: ElementIsVisible]